# Wordpress-SQL syntax error use near 'AND comment_type

Tags: wordpress, syntax

I am using Wordpress 4.8 with Woocommerce. Whenever I try to update a product in woocommerce I get an error message in the error log. After hitting the update button, it takes a an extended period of to process the update request, then it does nothing.

WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

> 'AND comment_type != 'log_note' ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT
>   10' at line 1 for query SELECT DrRDkCEPcomments.* FROM
>   DrRDkCEPcomments AND comment_type != 'log_note' ORDER BY
>   comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 10
>
> made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts,
>   WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts

I have already tried to following fixes:

- Reinstalled Wordpress
- Reinstalled all plugins
- Removed any plugins that had not been tested with current version of wordpress
- Repaired all tables in myPHP

Comment: if this is not a common error with wordpress installation and you're not a programmer, you'll need someone(with right amount of experience) to look at the contents of 'wp-blog-header.php' since it is originating from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you write manual query into database because I saw this query wronge

```
SELECT DrRDkCEPcomments.* FROM DrRDkCEPcomments AND comment_type != 'log_note' ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 10
```

And this correct query that I updated on your above query.

```
SELECT DrRDkCEPcomments.* FROM DrRDkCEPcomments where comment_type != 'log_note' ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 10
```

Note: Please try both query with PHPMyAdmin first you will see the error.